# What can cause a mysql datetime field to hold a value like 2015-00-06 01:36:00 (notice the 0 for month)

Tags: mysql

I'm having an issue where the following line of sql (it's run from a C program) will *sometimes* cause a bad date to appear in the table:

`UPDATE queue_members SET status=2, idlesince='1500059950' WHERE id=57206`

Then checking the table (note the 00 for month):

```
mysql> SELECT id, idlesince FROM queue_members WHERE Month(idlesince) = 0 and Year(idlesince) != 0;
...
| 57206 | 2015-00-06 00:38:00 |
```

Of course the C script runs many of these SQL statements and most of them run just fine:

`UPDATE queue_members SET status=2, idlesince='1500059864' WHERE id=56294`

```
mysql> SELECT id, idlesince FROM queue_members WHERE id=56294;
...
| 56294 | 2017-07-14 15:40:41 |
```

While I'd love to know why some statements cause the issue and others don't when they look pretty much the same, I am curious as to why mysql can store a date like that (or display it) when it's clearly invalid? How is it storing the date in a datetime field that results in that kind of a date?

I'm running:

```
% mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.33, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Comment: What is the type of the column `idlesince`? To me it appears that the problem is on the side of who wrote the date... Must be a PEBKAC issue.

Comment: It's a datetime column

Comment: The date is returned from the C time() function, so is a unix timestamp number.

Comment: And is it common to write a unix timestamp into a datetime column? `idlesince='1500059950'`

Comment: The odd thing is this code has been running for over 3 years. Yet suddenly last night this issue came up.  We haven't updated the database or the C code in any way.  I've tested updating the database that way manually and it works fine every time.

Comment: I published an answer. It worked during 3 years because nobody ever checked and MySQL is permissive, All your DB is corrupted. We can only empathize now... ;-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to write a timestamp:

`UPDATE queue_members SET status=2,`**`idlesince='1500059950'`**`WHERE id=57206`

But as stated in your comments, your column is of type `DATETIME`. You have to convert your timestamp to a proper `DATETIME` format with [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Actually, it appears more obviously after second review:

`'1500059950'` is `15` then `00`, then `05`, etc.

- 15: interpreted as `YY` so 2015
- 00: month `MM` as `00` (yup, MySQL *is* permissive)
- 05: day, transforms to `06` but because hour is `99`

etc.